# POST FormData object to Razor Page

Tags: javascript, c#, post, razor-pages

I have an issue with a simple jQuery $.post in my application. I have tried many methods and solutions on the internet to no avail. When post request is sent I see 400 error

```
public class RecoveryAdhocInvoicingModel : PageModel
{                                                                                  
    Public IActionResult OnPostDoJob(string invNo, string account)
    {
        //var emailAddress = Request.Form["emailaddress"];
        // do something with emailAddress
        return new JsonResult("");
    }                                                                                   
}
```

In my script the $.post method is called via button click:

```
$('#submitBtnUpdateJob').click(function (evt) {
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("invNo", $('#adhocInvoiceNumber').val());
            formdata.append("account", $('#invoiceAccountInput').val());

    $.post(window.location.href + '?handler=DoJob', JSON.stringify(formdata), function () {
         alert('Posted');
    });                                                                                   
});
```

[Solution folder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXrod.png)

Comment: the 400 ERROR path seems to be correct: https://myip:44388/Recovery/RecoveryAdhocInvoicing?handler=DoJob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `RequestVerificationToken` header to the request.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    url: window.location.href + '?handler=DoJob',
    data: {
        "invNo": $('#adhocInvoiceNumber').val(),
        "account": $('#invoiceAccountInput').val()
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}).done(function (response) {
    alert('Posted');
});
```

Documentation: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification#ajax-post-requests-and-json