# Calling asp-page handler method from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

i try to call asp-page handler method from javascript but i still get a 400 bad request
i have a post handler in a razor page which is OnPost and i try to call it with an httprequest from the js file
in the pagemodel i only have 2 handlers post and get
so i want to heat the post handler from the js file in order to execute the logique

```
the js code : 

async function fetchMakeCredentialOptions(formData) {
    let response = await fetch('Account/PasswordLessRegistration?handler=Submit',
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData, 
        header:
        {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

the c# code :
 
namespace IdentityServerHost.Pages.PasswordLessLogin
{
     public class Index : PageModel
    {
        private IFido2 _fido2;
        public static readonly DevelopmentInMemoryStore PasswordlessStore = new DevelopmentInMemoryStore();
        private readonly AdminIdentityDbContext _context;
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public Index(IFido2 fido2,

            AdminIdentityDbContext context)
        {
            _fido2 = fido2;
            _context = context;
        }
        private string FormatException(Exception e)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", e.Message, e.InnerException != null ? " (" + e.InnerException.Message + ")" : "");
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost([FromForm] string username,
                                                [FromForm] string displayName,
                                                [FromForm] string attType,
                                                [FromForm] string authType,
                                                [FromForm] bool requireResidentKey,
                                                [FromForm] string userVerification)
        {
            try
            {
                // user must already exist in Identity
                var identityUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.UserName == "anis");
                if (identityUser == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("User not found");
                }

                if (!HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated())
                {
                    throw new Exception("User is not authenticated");
                };

                // 1. Get user from DB by username (in our example, auto create missing users)
                var user = PasswordlessStore.GetOrAddUser(username, () => new Fido2User
                {
                    DisplayName = displayName,
                    Name = username,
                    Id = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username) // byte representation of userID is required
                });

                // 2. Get user existing keys by username
                var existingKeys = PasswordlessStore.GetCredentialsByUser(user).Select(c => c.Descriptor).ToList();

                // 3. Create options
                var authenticatorSelection = new AuthenticatorSelection
                {
                    RequireResidentKey = requireResidentKey,
                    UserVerification = userVerification.ToEnum<UserVerificationRequirement>()
                };

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authType))
                    authenticatorSelection.AuthenticatorAttachment = authType.ToEnum<AuthenticatorAttachment>();

                var exts = new AuthenticationExtensionsClientInputs()
                {
                    Extensions = true,
                    UserVerificationIndex = true,
                    Location = true,
                    UserVerificationMethod = true,
                    BiometricAuthenticatorPerformanceBounds = new AuthenticatorBiometricPerfBounds
                    {
                        FAR = float.MaxValue,
                        FRR = float.MaxValue
                    }
                };
                var options = _fido2.RequestNewCredential(user, existingKeys, authenticatorSelection, attType.ToEnum<AttestationConveyancePreference>(), exts);
                // 4. Temporarily store options, session/in-memory cache/redis/db
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("fido2.attestationOptions", options.ToJson());

                // 5. return options to client
                return new JsonResult(options);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new JsonResult(new CredentialCreateOptions { Status = "error", ErrorMessage = FormatException(e) });
            }
            return new JsonResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```

the content of formdata variable is :

```
  var data = new FormData();
    data.append('username', username);
    data.append('displayName', displayName);
    data.append('attType', attestation_type);
    data.append('authType', authenticator_attachment);
    data.append('userVerification', user_verification);
    data.append('requireResidentKey', require_resident_key);
```

Comment: Try rename the C# handler to: `OnPostSubmit`.

Comment: i already do it and still did not work

Comment: You're fetching `PasswordLessRegistration`. Is that the path to `Index `? Do you have a `@page` directive on that page?

Comment: Please see this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73837830/post-formdata-object-to-razor-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to call asp-page handler method from javascript but i still get
> a 400 bad request i have a post handler in a razor page which is
> OnPost and i try to call it with an httprequest from the js file in
> the pagemodel i only have 2 handlers post and get so i want to heat
> the post handler from the js file in order to execute the logique

Well, as you have only one OnPost  method on your Index Razor page so, no need to explicitly writing page handler name as `?handler=Submit` but this not causing the error of 400 you are getting.

In addition, if you have many OnPost method, in that case this `?handler=Submit` means you have one method of OnPostSubmit. It can still send request to your page handler since there is only one OnPost method other than it won't work.

Now let's move directly to your issue which causing the error of `400 (Bad Request)` is your missing `RequestVerificationToken` within the request header. As you can see below:

[image]

While, you would sent ajax request from razor page either you have to use RequestVerificationToken in order to prevent [Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Or you can consider using [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.ignoreantiforgerytokenattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which is not recommended that would allow to reach your request to your page handler or method accordingly.

How to resolve:

In order to resolve your issue, you should include RequestVerificationToken within your request header. Thus, your complete request should be as following:

```
async function fetchMakeCredentialOptions(formData) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5062/PageHandlerTesing?handler=Submit", {
            headers: { 
               "RequestVerificationToken": document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        });
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log("Success:", result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
}
```

Full Demo:

Razor Page Model:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Diaplay Name")]
    public string displayName { get; set; }


}
```

PageHandlerTesing.cshtml.cs:

```
public class PageHandlerTesingModel : PageModel
 {
     //private IFido2 _fido2;
     //public static readonly DevelopmentInMemoryStore PasswordlessStore = new DevelopmentInMemoryStore();
     //private readonly AdminIdentityDbContext _context;
     [BindProperty]
     public InputModel Input { get; set; }
     public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
     {
         return Page();
     }
     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost([FromForm] string username,
                                             [FromForm] string displayName
                                             )
     {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

**Note:**  Please, notice that, I have omitted few code snippet which is not relevant to simulate the investigation, do remember to set those missing snippet within your real app code.

PageHandlerTesing.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemoApp.Pages.PageHandlerTesingModel
@{
}

<form method="post" class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Input.username" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="Input.username" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Input.displayName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="Input.displayName" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 offset-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts
    {
    <script>

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            async function fetchMakeCredentialOptions(formData) {
                try {
                    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5062/PageHandlerTesing?handler=Submit", {
                        headers: { 
                           "RequestVerificationToken": document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value,
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                        },
                        method: "POST",
                        body: formData,
                    });
                    const result = await response.json();
                    console.log("Success:", result);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                }
            }

            const formData = new FormData();
            const username = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Input.username"]')[0].value;
            const displayName = document.querySelectorAll('[name="Input.displayName"]')[0].value;

            console.log(username);
            console.log(displayName);

            formData.append("username", username);
            formData.append("displayName", displayName);

            fetchMakeCredentialOptions(formData);
        });

    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you still need more details, please [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-1)

Comment: Glad to know that you made it work.